# Java - how can I get the text from TextField

Tags: java, textfield

I'm a bloody beginner. I wanna make a login-screen but I encounter a compiler error:

```
package passwordmanager;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    JLabel username;
    JLabel password;
    JTextField user;
    JPasswordField pass;
    JButton login;
    public Frame()
    {
        //Frame
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(425, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Password-Login");

        //Label 1
        username = new JLabel("Benutzernahme:");
        username.setBounds(16, 50, 500, 15);

            //Font
            Font font1 = new Font("", Font.BOLD, 13);

        username.setFont(font1);    
        add(username);

        //Label2
        password = new JLabel("Passwort:");
        password.setBounds(16, 134, 200, 20);
        password.setFont(font1);
        add(password);

        //TextField
        user = new JTextField();
        user.setBounds(16, 76, 350, 30);
        user.setVisible(true);
        add(user);

        //PasswordField
        pass = new JPasswordField();
        pass.setBounds(16, 160, 350, 30);
        pass.setVisible(true);
        add(pass);

        //Button
        login = new JButton();
        login.setBounds(0, 0, 5, 5);
        add(login);
    }

    String myusername = user.getText();
    String mypassword = new String(pass.getPassword());

    public class Listener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(myusername.equalsIgnoreCase("whatever") && mypassword.equalsIgnoreCase("whatever"))
            {
                System.out.println("NICE");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse says that this string

```
 String myusername = user.getText();
```

is wrong. Do you know how I can fix this?

Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: Please post the 'bloody' error message in full ;)

Comment: you are trying to get the values outside the method or function (accessors) which is invalid do it in method or in constructor...

Comment: In the future, if your code doesn't compile, and you're asking about it, post the full compilation error in your question itself. It's actually quite important. Even better -- first search this site on the error message as likely the question has been asked before (as this question has, at least 10,000 times).

Comment: [Link to similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java++syntax+error+on+token)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
String myusername = user.getText();
String mypassword = new String(pass.getPassword());
```

Has to be in a method or constructor...You can't place that code there. You can declare variables there but can't perform operations.

This part:

```
myusername = user.getText();
mypassword = new String(pass.getPassword());
```

Should be in your constructor...or some other method.
You probably want it here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    myusername = user.getText();
    mypassword = new String(pass.getPassword());
    if(myusername.equalsIgnoreCase("whatever") && mypassword.equalsIgnoreCase("whatever"))
    {
            System.out.println("NICE");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisKlein no problem! Glad I could help!